# Cakephp customizing the output of date input form helpers

Tags: cakephp, date, input, html-helper

I got

```
echo $this->Form->input('birthdate', array( 'label' => __('Geburtsdatum', true)
                        , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 70
                        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 10 ));
```

and in the model I've set birthdate to date. Now Cakephp spits out three select boxes, which I absolutely adore. BUT it also spits out two ugly dashes / hyphens in between, which I want to get rid of.

SELECTBOX - SELECTBOX - SELECTBOX

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `separator` option you can specify:

```
'separator' => 'YOUR_SEPARATOR'
```

Comment: even more than exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much!

Comment: I could have sworn this was spelled "seperator". Doh.
That's why it didn't work for me!
Reminds me of my first html experiences, and the "colour" css not working...