# Change dashes to slashes in cakephp generated date selects

Tags: date, cakephp

When cake generates the 3 select boxes for a `'type'=>'date'` input is there a way to change the dashes in between each select to slashes instead? Just for visual customization. I realize I can do it with javascript but I'm trying to see if I can avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer

[Cakephp customizing the output of date input form helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162322/cakephp-customizing-the-output-of-date-input-form-helpers)

`'separator' => 'YOUR_SEPARATOR'`